# user notifications in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'm building an application using **Grails 2.5.1** , i want to implement a user's notification service ,similar as **Stack overflow** for instance when the user has unread messages it notifies the user as soon as he login . is there a plugin or a handy way to achieve this ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want some data (ex: unread messages) on demand (login), then you could include this in the action's returned map or fetch the data from a separate Ajax call when the document.event fires and manipulate the DOM (easily done through jquery, angular, etc.)

---

If you are looking to update the DOM asynchronously based on events that happen server-side (another user sends a message and you would like to 'instantly' alert the current user), then things become more complicated.
**Spring Websocket**
There is a grails plugin that we have experimented with and have had success with: [grails-spring-websocket](https://github.com/zyro23/grails-spring-websocket).  Check out the link for examples and more info.

There is a bean `brokerMessagingTemplate` that is injected within your service class that has methods to publish a message.  On the client, you subscribe to the corresponding message url using javascript.  When the callback function is executed, a message has been published - manipulate the DOM as needed.

There are also some controller annotations provided by the plugin, but I don't have experience with them.